# How to make input that can be re-entered if needed

Tags: python-3.x

I've been facing this problem for a while and still can't figure it out. I've made a program that calculates variables from equal. In one part of it, user is asked to input value of all variables one by one, and mark variable that should be calculated with letter 'n'. I would like to have there an option for re-entering value of variable, when user makes mistake. For example when user's input is BACKSPACE, it should jump back to previous variable and let the user re-enter the value. I hope I described it good enough. Do you guys have an idea how to make this work? Thanks for you respond.

This is what the code looks like. 'premenne' is a dictionary containing values of variables of equal. For loop goes through that dictionary and assignes inputed value to each of those variables.

```
   premenne = {
    'm1': 0.0,
    'c1': 0.0,
    't1': 0.0,
    't': 0.0,
    'm2': 0.0,
    'c2': 0.0,
    't2': 0.0

}

for x in premenne:
    premenne[x] = input(x + ': ')
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want. It would be better if you showed us some code regarding what you have done so far, and what are the problems with it along with some sample inputs.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Here it is...hope it would help

Comment: If it still isn't clear just tell me and I'll upload more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for x in premenne:
    while True:
        try:
            val = input('{}: '.format(x))
            val = float(val)
        except:
            # catch-all, conversion to float failed, ask again
            continue
        else:
            premenne[x] = val
            break
```

I purposely made it with more lines of code than really required, for you to understand better. The idea is that it will keep asking the user to enter a value for x **as long as the value cannot be converted to a float** (as it looks like all your values are floats)

Now the shorter version of the same code:

```
for x in premenne:
    while True:
        try:
            premenne[x] = float(input('{}: '.format(x)))
            break
        except:
            continue
```

Last but not least, to initialise your dict with all the values equal to 0.0 use this:

```
premenne = dict.fromkeys(['m1', 'c1', 't1', 't', 'm2', 'c2', 't2'], 0.0)
```

Comment: That isn't what I need but anyway thank you for your time!